# Safe way to declare a private function in Dojo

Tags: javascript, function, dojo, private

Pattern to create private functions in Dojo?

The Dojo documentation advocates the use of _underscore to denote a function as private, but this is obviously just a convention and doesn't actually create a private function e.g.

```
define([
   "dojo/_base/declare"
],
function (declare) {
   return declare(null, {

       getPrivateData: function () {
           _myPrivateFunction();
       },

       _myPrivateFunction: function () {
           return "Data from private function";
       }
   });
});
```

I've looked at the questions on SO about private variables in Dojo, but none of them reflect my requirement. However, one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248081/dojos-private-variable) includes a sample from the Dojo documentation showing how to create a private class.

My question is, is there any reason why the same pattern should not be used to create a private function? e.g.

```
 define([
"dojo/_base/declare"
],
function (declare) {

    var myPrivateFunction = function() {
        return "Data from private function";
    };

    return declare(null, {

        getPrivateData: function () {
            myPrivateFunction();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: The second example looks perfectly fine if that's what you require.

Comment: Well, that's what I think but, as I'm new to Dojo, I wanted to check.  Everything else I've seen (including the Dojo documentation) advocates the use of '_' (with the function defined in the main declare) to define a (pseudo) private function.

Comment: That's true, but the privacy levels are different. The `myPrivateFunction` function that is 'hidden' in the module's closure is 'more' private that the `myPrivateFunction` function that is declared in the `declare` call. The use for the former is if you absolutely don't need external access to that function. The use for the latter is if external access is required, such as with a 'subclass'.

Comment: If it helps, I've always thought the '_' functions should be thought as *internal* functions rather than *private* in terms of other languages.  Your second construction is fine; it's just JavaScript after all.